# Vocab to describe Image Data / Pictures

Tags: tool-request

I've seen a page where they describe technology along with a Vocab to describe imagery data. It allows a client to zoom into very large images which are then tiled and loaded and set focal points to define what should be seen when minimizing the image. A little bit like the HTML picture element. I forgot the name of this page. Does anyone know what I mean?

Comment: Do you mean tiled rendering? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_rendering

Comment: If it's a web design thing, you might be better off asking the question on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Could you please describe the vocabulary part? It would make the question off-topic.

Comment: It IS a vocabulary (plus ther were working examples of this, using the vocab for a demo) as I remember it was embedded in an RDF context.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to [Focal Point](https://github.com/adamdbradley/focal-point)?

> **Focal Point: Pure HTML/CSS Adaptive Images Framework**
>
> A small set of CSS classnames to help keep images cropped on the focal point for responsive designs. Using only HTML/CSS, web authors can specify an image's focal point, which stays as the image's primary focus as the image scales on responsive webpages.

If this is not what you are looking for, they also link to [related resources](https://github.com/adamdbradley/focal-point#other-resources) that might be of interest to you.

Comment: No that's not the one. The one I mean as an extensive web page with a demo of their image viewer based on JavaScript.